# How to put that remote json response into JS variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

How to put that remote JSON response into JS variable So I can then use the variable in an IF Else statement?

```
  $.get("https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=test", function (response) {
        $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response.country_name, null, 4));
    }, "jsonp");
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: I just need to put it's response in a javascript variable so I can then use it in if statement, sorry i'm totally ignorant in Js so I will type what I wanna do in PHP but i need the equivalent of that code in js
// i know that first line is wrong but just wanna show you what i mean
$country = response.country_name;
If ($country = "France") {
echo "This is France";
}

Comment: Use the [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) function. Example `var v = JSON.parse('true')`;

Comment: @dbvega Thanks for the reply, I'm sorry I'm totally ignorant in js so far, could you please show me other example using my code above, would appreciate that

Comment: @IslamMohamed But it's already a variable. Just do `if(response.country_name == "France")`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I tried doing writing that 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response.country_name;
but this returned undfined value

Comment: @IslamMohamed So above that try to do `response = JSON.parse(response);` - if that doesn't work, then your API isn't returning what you think it is

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Unfortunately it still doesn't work however I get the expected response.. check here please
https://jsfiddle.net/6wtf0q4g/975/

Comment: @IslamMohamed Worked for me... https://jsfiddle.net/6wtf0q4g/976/

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton oh i see, that was stupid from me, i was defining the variable outside the closing brackets of the JSON snippet :)
Thanks so much

Comment: @IslamMohamed Glad that I could help

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton One last thing please, I'm wondering why if when i set response.country_name in a global variable I still can't use it outside that function?
https://jsfiddle.net/6wtf0q4g/977/

Comment: @IslamMohamed This is something a lot of people have a hard time grasping. This code is asynchronous, this means it's not necessarily ran in the order it is read. When the `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` code is executing in your code, the `$.get` request probably hasn't even finished yet. Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6wtf0q4g/978/

Comment: Thanks so much @GrumpyCrouton